# Distinct sum of a dataset

Tags: sql

I have a dataset like this :

```
TYPE count
TYPE1 50
TYPE2 20
TYPE1 10
TYPE2 30
```

i want to sum the distinct type in a same line :

```
TYPE count
TYPE1 60
TYPE2 50
```

Can you help me please ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a more clear representation of the dataset/tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to use is `GROUP BY` combined with an aggregate function, `SUM()` for a table.

Say you have a table, simply defined as

```sql
CREATE TABLE dataset(type varchar(50), cnt int);
```

with the dataset you provided:

```sql
INSERT INTO dataset (type, cnt)
VALUES
  ('TYPE1', 50),
  ('TYPE2', 20),
  ('TYPE1', 10),
  ('TYPE2', 30)
```

That'll allow you to query as such:

```sql
SELECT type, SUM(cnt)
FROM dataset
GROUP BY type
```

See also SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7edf02/2/0

Answer (score 2):

You seem to need a basic aggregation query:

```sql
SELECT TYPE, SUM(count) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY TYPE;
```